# Calling Laravel function dynamically

Tags: php, laravel

I just started learning Laravel.

I get an error message of "Error: Call to undefined function addPost()". What seems to be the problem in my code?

$command == "addPost";

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    function checkPostsCommand(Request $request) {
        $command = $request->btn;

        $data = $this->$command($request->all());

        return response()->json($data);
    }
    private function addPost() {
        return 'wew';
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are just learning, don't make a habit of writing code like this. You are calling an arbitrary function based on user input. Even if this is only within your controller this is a recipe for trouble. For example if someone passes value `checkPostsCommand` to `btn` you have an infinite loop which can drain server resources and be a prime vector for a DoS attack. You will need to validate your input and only allow a specific set of values to `btn` in which case you have no real gain from coding in this way

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for the insights! I've edited my code above. I tried to do what you said, thankfully it did not ddos. An error message occurred: exception: "TypeError".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it like this :

```
$this->$command();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    function checkPostsCommand(Request $request)
    {
        $command = $request->btn;
        return $this->addPost();
    }
    private function addPost() {
        echo 'wew';
    }
}
```

Comment: no he does not. private function works too

Comment: I have edited my answer have a look now,